# named route not generating appropriate url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My named route is not generating the appropriate url helper for the following nested route:

```
  resources :contacts do
    match :promote_to_client, via: [:get,:post], on: :member, as: :promote_to_client
```

I am expecting a helper like `promote_to_client_path`. However, instead it is giving me `promote_to_client_contact_path` (which is the default). What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails prefixes the helper names with whatever resource they are nested in:

```
resources :books do
  resorces :chapters
end
```

Would give `book_chapters_path` etc. This can be customized through [the `shallow_prefix` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
resources :books, shallow_prefix: 'secret' do
  resorces :chapters
end
```

`secret_chapters_path`